# Allow 2 digit number after the decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i am trying to restrict user to input 2 digit number after the  decimal.The below  functionality is working but i am not able to modify the last two digit.suppose I have entered number 3456.78 and i want to modify 3456.68 it is not allowing.

```js
$('.PMT_AMT').keypress(function(event) {

  var $this = $(this);
  if ((event.which != 46 || $this.val().indexOf('.') != -1) &&
    ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) &&
      (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8))) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  var text = $(this).val();
  if ((event.which == 46) && (text.indexOf('.') == -1)) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if ($this.val().substring($this.val().indexOf('.')).length > 3) {
        $this.val($this.val().substring(0, $this.val().indexOf('.') + 3));
      }
    }, 1);
  }

  if ((text.indexOf('.') != -1) &&
    (text.substring(text.indexOf('.')).length > 2) &&
    (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8) &&
    ($(this)[0].selectionStart >= text.length - 2)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="PMT_AMT">
```

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: why dont you make use of regex

Comment: And why are you using `setTimeout`? Geez, there is definitely some weird pieces of code here. This one seems very complex for what you want to do.

Comment: A regular expression is definitely the best choice here. One possibility: `<input class="PMT_AMT" pattern="^\d+(\.(\d\d)?)?$">`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possibility that uses a regular expression. Save the old input value on `keypress`, and if the new value on `keyup` does not validate, reset to that old value.

You need to validate on `keypress` as well, because otherwise, if the user types very fast, an invalid value can be saved:

```js
const re = /^\d+(\.\d{0,2})?$/;
let oldVal;
$('.PMT_AMT').keypress(function(event) {
  const { value } = this;
  if (re.test(value)) oldVal = value;
});
$('.PMT_AMT').keyup(function(event) {
  const newVal = this.value;
  if (!re.test(newVal)) this.value = oldVal;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="PMT_AMT">
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution creates a prediction and tests the regular expression against that instead.

```js
$('.PMT_AMT').keypress(function(event) {
  if(!/^\d*(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(
    this.value.slice(0, this.selectionStart)
    + String.fromCharCode(event.which)
    + this.value.slice(this.selectionEnd)
    )) event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="PMT_AMT">
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use jQuery and not just browser functionality?

```
<input type="number" step="0.01">
```

On submit the browser will check if the submitted value of the input field has maximum two decimals.